# What are the limits of the prefix 'step' to describe relationships?

Tags: word-choice, kinship-terms

Is my mother's step-father, my step-grandfather?  To what extent is it usual to extend the prefix 'step'?

Can we speak of 'step-cousins', step-aunts and step-uncles etc? If we can it must make for considerable complication in how such relationships are defined.

Comment: I think if it goes beyond the direct relationship (i.e: stepfather, stepbrother, stepsister and stepmother) it gets very confusing.

Comment: You should add "in-laws" to this too...you can marry into such a complicated relation!

Comment: While I understand the theoretical value of the *step-* clarification, after the immediacy of whether you were there when I was conceived, the designation has little value (except for genetic disease screening). My *step-brother* is my brother. My wife is my grandson's grandmother (even though she is not his father's mother). She has been in a grandmotherly relationship from the moment he was conceived!

Comment: @bib I don't understand where you're coming from. Having the same childhood and sharing the same genetic pool has a big impact on your relationship and life in general. Your step-brother IS your brother, but that doesn't imply that it's not worth noting that he is your step-brother.

Comment: @Jeremy I have two step-brothers who *are* my brothers,and have been for 48 years. Most relationships beyond immediate family (e.g., step -grandparents, etc.) run for the entire life of the younger *step-* relatives, yielding no differences except DNA. And DNA is highly overrated.

Comment: If you have a mother and father and your father dies, but later your mother remarries, the person is not your true biological father but he is still you father so he is your step father. So pretty much if a relive dies and is replaced or on a different replaced relatives side of the family. He is your step-relitive.

Comment: And let's not forget that the distinction is different if you share only half your parentage (half-siblings), and interestingly, there is no distinction if you share none at all (adopted siblings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of the combining form **[step-](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/step-?q=step-)**, Oxford Dictionaries only says:

> denoting a relationship resulting from a remarriage

Past immediate step-parents or step-siblings, I no longer find the distinction useful.

Introduce your mom's stepfather as "My mom's stepfather."

Likewise with your stepmom's sister, your aunt's stepdaughter, and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

I did a quick NGrams, and -father has 106, to -grandfathers 9, -uncle -4 and cousin 1.  And father was far more common in the 1860s than that.

I left out the female side, aside from half of cousin.

So it appears the more distant the relation, the frequency of *stepping* drops by about a factor of 10.